# How to display the current year with next year something like 2018-2019 in the dropdown?

Tags: php, html

I want a year like this in my dropdown

```
2018-2019
2019-2020
2020-2021
2021-2022
2022-2023
```

but I am getting like this

```
2018-2019
2019-2019
2020-2019
2021-2019
2022-2019
```

I tried below code. I think there is some increment issue. Would you help me out in this?

```
 <select  class="form-control" name="Duration" id="Duration">
 <option value="" disabled selected>Year</option>
  <?php 
  for ($i = date('Y'); $i <= date('Y')+5; $i++) {?>
 <option value="<?php echo $i;?>-<?php echo date("Y")+1;?>" <?php echo set_select('Duration', $i, False); ?> ><?php echo $i;?>-<?php echo date("Y")+1;?> </option> 
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're always incrementing the *current year* instead of the *current year being displayed*. Just use `$i + 1` instead of `date("Y") + 1`:

```
<select  class="form-control" name="Duration" id="Duration">
 <option value="" disabled selected>Year</option>
  <?php 
  for ($i = date('Y'); $i <= date('Y')+5; $i++) {?>
 <option value="<?php echo $i;?>-<?php echo $i + 1;?>" <?php echo set_select('Duration', $i, False); ?> ><?php echo $i;?>-<?php echo $i + 1;?> </option> 
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thanks for the answer. It's working.